# UrlDownloadToFile ошибка E_ABORT Operation aborted

Tags: c++, visual-studio, url

Код C++, Visual Studio 2019, urlmon подключен, вызываю так:

```
HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, L"http://site.com/st", L"D:\\asd.html", 0, 0);
```

Соответственно, st - файл на сервере, D:\asd.html - файл для сохранения на ПК.
Получаю запрос и последующий сброс соединения (скрин ниже с WireShark). При этом когда я пробовал использовать URLOpenStream с теми же параметрами, не считая файла, все работало как нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что по умолчанию нельзя использовать корень диска (как и некоторые другие пути) для сохранения файла, решил опытным путём. Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь скинет ссылку на объяснения.